# Há um diagrama do banco de dados disponível no Data StackExchange e uma descrição do conteúdo de cada tabela?

Tags: suporte

É sabido da existência do [Data StackExchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/) que permite os usuários fazerem consultas por SQL no banco da rede de comunidades da Stack. O banco é somente leitura e é atualizado todos os domingos às 3:00 (UTC).

Quando acessado para criar uma nova consulta é exibido uma lista das tabelas que podem ser utilizadas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Há disponível um diagrama de como essas tabelas se relacionam para facilitar as consultas?
- Há uma descrição do que cada tabela armazena como conteúdo e o que é cada coluna?

Comment: Vi que existe a pergunta [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/369699), seria interessante ao meu ver termos isso em português também para facilitar o uso do Data.

Comment: Se traduzir as duas respostas que tem lá no meta.SE e colocar como resposta aqui já serve?

Comment: @hkotsubo acredito que sim; mas se não, já será um excelente início :D

Comment: Bom, tá lá a resposta. Mas não consegui traduzir 100%, tem coisas que eu não sei exatamente o que é (ou não tinha certeza absoluta) e deixei como estava mesmo...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>*Esta é uma tradução/adaptação das respostas [desta pergunta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/401803).*</sup>

---

**Sobre esta lista:**

- **chaves estrangeiras** estão formatadas como [*links*](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts) para a respectiva tabela
- nomes de tabelas em *itálico* indicam que elas estão tanto no *Data Dump* (em [Archive.org](https://ia800500.us.archive.org/22/items/stackexchange/readme.txt)) quanto no [SEDE (Stack Exchange Data Explorer)](https://data.stackexchange.com/)

---

### *Posts*  / PostsWithDeleted

Na tabela `Posts` estão todas as postagens (perguntas e respostas) não-deletadas. `PostsWithDeleted` inclui também as postagens deletadas, além de possuir as mesmas colunas da tabela `Posts`, mas [em postagens deletadas, alguns campos não são preenchidos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266431) (estes estão marcados abaixo com <sup>1</sup>).

- `Id`<sup>1</sup>
- `PostTypeId`<sup>1</sup> *(valores listados na tabela [`PostTypes`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types))*
  <sub>1 = Pergunta

  2 = Resposta

  3 = Wiki de tag órfão

  4 = Fragmento de wiki de tag

  5 = Wiki de tag

  6 = Nomeação de Moderador

  7 = "Wiki placeholder" *(o único caso parece ser a [descrição da eleição de moderador](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8041931/body))*

  8 = Privilege wiki</sub>
- [`AcceptedAnswerId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts) *(presente somente se `PostTypeId = 1`)*
- [`ParentId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts&pk=Id)<sup>1</sup> *(presente somente se `PostTypeId = 2`)*
- `CreationDate`<sup>1</sup> - *data de criação*
- `DeletionDate`<sup>1</sup> *(não-nulo apenas na tabela `PostsWithDeleted`. Postagens deletadas não aparecem na tabela `Posts`. Esta coluna não existe no Data Dump.)*
- `Score`<sup>1</sup> - *pontuação*
- `ViewCount` *(nullable)* - *contador de visualizações*
- `Body` *([como HTML renderizado](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51177/include-markdown-post-bodies-in-the-data-dump) em vez de Markdown)*
- [`OwnerUserId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users) *(presente somente se o usuário não foi deletado; sempre é -1 para wikis de tag, isto é, o usuário "Community" é o dono delas)*
- `OwnerDisplayName` *(nullable)*
- [`LastEditorUserId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users) *(nullable)* - *ID do último usuário a editar*
- `LastEditorDisplayName` *(nullable)*
- `LastEditDate` (e.g. `2009-03-05T22:28:34.823`) - *data e hora da edição mais recente (nullable)*
- `LastActivityDate` (e.g. `2009-03-11T12:51:01.480`) - *data e hora da atividade mais recente da postagem*
- `Title` *(nullable)*
- `Tags`<sup>1</sup> *(nullable)*
- `AnswerCount` *(nullable)*
- `CommentCount` *(nullable)*
- `FavoriteCount` *(nullable)*
- `ClosedDate`<sup>1</sup> *(presente somente se a pergunta foi fechada)*
- `CommunityOwnedDate` *(presente somente se a postagem é Wiki da comunidade)*

---

### *Users*

- `Id`
- `Reputation` - *reputação*
- `CreationDate` - *data de criação*
- `DisplayName`
- `LastAccessDate` *([Data e hora da última vez que o usuário carregou uma página, atualizado no máximo a cada 30 minutos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/294750/230261))*
- `WebsiteUrl`
- `Location`
- `AboutMe`
- `Views` *([Quantidade de vezes que o perfil foi visto](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311938/what-is-views-of-users-in-the-database-schema-documentation))*
- `UpVotes` *([Quantos votos positivos o usuário já deu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260897/what-is-upvotes-of-users-in-database-schema-documentation))*
- `DownVotes`
- `ProfileImageUrl`
- `EmailHash` *(nem sempre vazio)*
- `AccountId`  *(Id do usuário na rede Stack Exchange)*

---

### *Comments*

- `Id`
- [`PostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts)
- `Score`
- `Text` *(texto do comentário)*
- `CreationDate`
- `UserDisplayName`
- [`UserId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users) *(Opcional. Ausente se o usuário foi deletado)*

---

### *Badges*

- `Id`
- [`UserId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users)
- `Name` *(Nome da medalha)*
- `Date` (e.g. `2008-09-15T08:55:03.923`)
- `Class`
  <sub>1 = Ouro

  2 = Prata

  3 = Bronze</sub>
- `TagBased` = *`True` se for uma medalha de tag*

---

### CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypes

- `Id`
- `IsUniversal`
- `MarkdownMini` *(markdown do motivo de fechamento)*
- `CreationDate`
- [`CreationModeratorId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users)
- `ApprovalDate`
- [`ApprovalModeratorId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users)
- `DeactivationDate`
- [`DeactivationModeratorId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users)

---

### PendingFlags

Apesar do nome, esta tabela na verdade contém votos e sinalizações de fechamento.

- `Id`
- `FlagTypeId` *(listados na tabela [`FlagTypes`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types))*
  <sub>13 = sinalização de fechamento

  14 = voto de fechamento

  15 = voto de reabertura</sub>
- [`PostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts)
- `CreationDate`
- `CloseReasonTypeId` *(listados na tabela [`CloseReasonTypes`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types))*
- `CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypeId`, *se `CloseReasonTypeId = 102 (fora do escopo)` (listado na tabela [`CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypes`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types))*
- [`DuplicateOfQuestionId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts), *se `CloseReasonTypeId` é 1 ou 101 (old duplicate or current duplicate)*
- `BelongsOnBaseHostAddress`, *para votos de fechamento e migração*

---

### PostFeedback

Guarda os votos positivos e negativos de visitantes anônimos e/ou usuários não-registrados. Veja [aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194939/158100)

- `Id`
- [`PostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts)
- `IsAnonymous`
- `VoteTypeId` *(listados na tabela [`VoteTypes`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types))*
  <sub>2 = UpMod

  3 = DownMod</sub>
- `CreationDate`

---

### *PostHistory*

- `Id`
- `PostHistoryTypeId` *(listados na tabela [`PostHistoryTypes`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types))*
  <sub>1 = Initial Title - título inicial *(apenas para perguntas)*

  2 = Initial Body - texto puro do corpo inicial do post

  3 = Initial Tags - lista inicial de tags *(apenas para perguntas)*

  4 = Edit Title - título modificado *(apenas para perguntas)*

  5 = Edit Body - corpo modificado do post (raw markdown)

  6 = Edit Tags - lista modificada de tags *(apenas para perguntas)*

  7 = Rollback Title - título revertido  *(apenas para perguntas)*

  8 = Rollback Body - corpo revertido (markdown puro)

  9 = Rollback Tags - lista revertida de tags *(apenas para perguntas)*

  10 = Post Closed - recebeu voto de fechamento

  11 = Post Reopened - recebeu voto de reabertura

  12 = Post Deleted - recebeu voto de remoção

  13 = Post Undeleted - recebeu voto de restauração

  14 = Post Locked - bloqueado por moderador

  15 = Post Unlocked - desbloqueado por moderador

  16 = Community Owned - post passou a ser do usuário Community

  17 = Post Migrated - post migrado - *agora substituído por 35/36 (saiu/entrou)*

  18 = Question Merged - pergunta mesclada com uma pergunta deletada

  19 = Question Protected - pergunta protegida por moderador.

  20 = Question Unprotected - pergunta desprotegida por moderador.

  21 = Post Disassociated - OwnerUserId removido do post por um admin

  22 = Question Unmerged - perguntas/votos restaurados para a pergunta previamente mesclada

  24 = Suggested Edit Applied - Edição sugerida aprovada

  25 = Post Tweeted - post *tweetado*

  31 = Comment discussion moved to chat - comentários movidos para o chat

  33 = Post notice added - *coluna `comment` contém chave estrangeira para PostNotices*

  34 = Post notice removed - *coluna `comment` contém chave estrangeira para PostNotices*

  35 = Post migrated away - *substitui id 17*

  36 = Post migrated here - *substitui id 17*

  37 = Post merge source - origem de mesclagem de post

  38 = Post merge destination - destino de mesclagem de post

  50 = Bumped by Community User - levada à página principal pelo usuário Community

  52 = Question became hot network question - pergunta adicionada à Hot Network Questions

  53 = Question removed from hot network questions by a moderator - pergunta removida da Hot Network Questions por um moderador</sub>

  Além disso, em [*dumps* antigos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/102644/230261) *(todos são palpites, pois parecem não estar mais presentes):*
  <sub>23 = Unknown dev related event

  26 = Vote nullification by dev *(ERM?)*

  27 = Post unmigrated/hidden moderator migration?

  28 = Unknown suggestion event

  29 = Unknown moderator event *(possibly de-wikification?)*

  30 = Unknown event *(too rare to guess)*</sub>
- [`PostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts)
- `RevisionGUID`: Às vezes, mais de um tipo de registro de histórico pode ser gravado para uma mesma ação. Estes serão agrupados por um mesmo RevisionGUID
- `CreationDate` (e.g. `2009-03-05T22:28:34.823`)
- [`UserId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users)
- `UserDisplayName`: preenchido se um usuário foi removido e não é mais referenciado pelo Id
- `Comment`: Comentário feito por quem editou a postagem.

  - Se `PostHistoryTypeId = 10`, este campo contém o `CloseReasonId` do motivo de fechamento (listado em `CloseReasonTypes`):
    <sub>***Motivos de fechamento antigos:***

    1 = Duplicata exata

    2 = Fora do escopo

    3 = Subjetivo e argumentativo

    4 = Não é uma pergunta

    7 = Muito localizado

    10 = Referência geral

    20 = Ruído ou sem sentido (Apenas no Meta)

    ***Motivos de fechamento atuais:***

    101 = Duplicata

    102 = Fora do escopo

    103 = Não está clara o suficiente

    104 = Muito ampla

    105 = Principalmente baseada em opiniões</sub>
  - Se `PostHistoryTypeId in (33,34)`, este campo contém o `PostNoticeId` do `PostNotice`
- `Text`: Um texto com o novo valor de determinada revisão
  <sub>- Se `PostHistoryTypeId in (10,11,12,13,14,15,19,20,35)`, esta coluna contém um JSON com todos os usuários que votaram para o que for indicado por `PostHistoryTypeId`</sub>
  <sub>- Se é um voto de fechamento para duplicata, o JSON contém um array das perguntas originais (`OriginalQuestionIds`)</sub>
  <sub>- Se `PostHistoryTypeId = 17`, esta coluna contém os detalhes da migração das URLs de origem e destino (`from <url>` e `to <url>`)</sub>

---

### *PostLinks*

- `Id` chave primária
- `CreationDate` quando o link foi criado
- [`PostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts) id da postagem
- [`RelatedPostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts) id da postagem relacionada
- `LinkTypeId`  tipo de link
  <sub>1 = Linked (`PostId` contém um link para `RelatedPostId`)

  3 = Duplicate (`PostId` é duplicata de `RelatedPostId`)</sub>

---

### PostNotices

- `Id`
- [`PostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts)
- [`PostNoticeTypeId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=postnoticetypes)
  <sub>1 = Citation needed

  2 = Current event

  3 = Insufficient explanation

  10 = Current answers are outdated

  11 = Draw attention

  12 = Improve details

  13 = Authoritative reference needed

  14 = Canonical answer required

  15 = Reward existing answer

  20 = Content dispute

  21 = Offtopic comments

  22 = Historical significance

  23 = Wiki Answer</sub>
- `CreationDate`
- `DeletionDate`
- `ExpiryDate`
- `Body`  *(quando presente, contém o texto customizado)*
- [`OwnerUserId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users)
- [`DeletionUserId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users)

---

### PostNoticeTypes

- `Id`
- `ClassId`
  <sub>1 = Historical lock - bloqueado por motivos históricos

  2 = Bounty - recompensa

  4 = Moderator notice - nota da moderação</sub>
- `Name`
- `Body`  *(contém o texto padrão)*
- `IsHidden`
- `Predefined`
- `PostNoticeDurationId`
  <sub>-1 = No duration specified - Duração não especificada

  1 = 7 days (bounty) - 7 dias (recompensa)</sub>

---

### PostTags

- [`PostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts)
- [`TagId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=tags)

---

### ReviewRejectionReasons

Motivos canônicos de rejeição de edições sugeridas. Veja [*Show all review rejection reasons*](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/199800/show-all-review-rejection-reasons)

- `Id`
- `Name`
- `Description`
- `PostTypeId` (para motivos que se aplicam apenas a Wiki (5) or Fragmento (6), caso contrário é nulo)

---

### ReviewTaskResults

- `Id`
- [`ReviewTaskId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=reviewtasks)
- `ReviewTaskResultTypeId` (listado em [`ReviewTaskResultTypes`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types))
  <sub>1 = Not Sure - Não tenho certeza

  2 = Approve - Aprovar (edições sugeridas)

  3 = Reject - Rejeitar (edições sugeridas)

  4 = Delete - Apagar (Publicações de baixa qualidade)

  5 = Edit - Editar (Primeiras publicações, Respostas tardias, Publicações de baixa qualidade)

  6 = Close - Fechar (Fechamento, Publicações de baixa qualidade)

  7 = Looks OK - Parece OK (Publicações de baixa qualidade)

  8 = Do Not Close - Não fechar (Fechamento)

  9 = Recommend Deletion - Recomendar exclusão (Publicações de baixa qualidade - respostas)

  10 = Recommend Close - Recomendar fechamento (Publicações de baixa qualidade - perguntas)

  11 = I'm Done - Terminei (first posts)

  12 = Reopen - Reabrir (Reabertura)

  13 = Leave Closed - Deixar fechada (Reabertura)

  14 = Edit and Reopen - Editar e reabrir (Reabertura)

  15 = Excellent - Excelente (avaliação da comunidade)

  16 = Satisfactory - Satisfatório (avaliação da comunidade)

  17 = Needs Improvement - Precisa de melhorias (avaliação da comunidade)

  18 = No Action Needed - Nenhuma ação é necessária (Primeiras publicações, Respostas tardias)</sub>
- `CreationDate`
- `RejectionReasonId` (para edições sugeridas, listado em `ReviewRejectionReasons`)
- `Comment`

---

### ReviewTasks

- `Id`
- `ReviewTaskTypeId` (listados em [`ReviewTaskTypes`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types))
  <sub>1 = Suggested Edit - Edições sugeridas

  2 = Close Votes - Votos para fechar

  3 = Low Quality Posts - Publicações de baixa qualidade

  4 = First Post - Primeiras publicações

  5 = Late Answer - Resposta tardia

  6 = Reopen Vote - Voto para reabrir

  7 = Community Evaluation - Avaliação da comunidade

  8 = Link Validation

  9 = Flagged Posts - Publicação sinalizada

  10 = Triage

  11 = Helper</sub>
- `CreationDate`
- `DeletionDate`
- `ReviewTaskStateId` (listados em [`ReviewTaskStates`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/199801/show-all-review-task-states))
  <sub>1 = Active - Ativo

  2 = Completed - Completo

  3 = Invalidated - Invalidado</sub>
- [`PostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts)
- [`SuggestedEditId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=suggestededits) (para edições sugeridas, que têm sua própria numeração por motivos históricos)
- [`CompletedByReviewTaskId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=ReviewTaskResults)  id associado ao `ReviewTaskResult` que guarda o resultado de uma revisão completada.

---

### SuggestedEdits

Se ambas as datas de aprovação e rejeição forem nulas, então a edição ainda está em revisão (e seu registro correspondente em `ReviewTasks` terá um status ativo).

- `Id`
- [`PostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts)
- `CreationDate`
- `ApprovalDate` - NULL se ainda não foi aprovado.
- `RejectionDate` - NULL se ainda não foi rejeitado.
- [`OwnerUserId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users)
- `Comment`
- `Text`
- `Title`
- `Tags`
- `RevisionGUID`

---

### SuggestedEditVotes

- `Id`
- [`SuggestedEditId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=suggestededits)
- [`UserId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users)
- `VoteTypeId` (listado na tabela [`VoteTypes`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types))
  <sub>2 = Approve (technically UpMod) - Aprovar

  3 = Reject (technically DownMod) - Rejeitar</sub>
- `CreationDate`
- [`TargetUserId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users)
- `TargetRepChange`

---

### *Tags*

- `Id`
- `TagName`
- `Count`
- [`ExcerptPostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts)  *(nullable) Id do Post que contém o fragmento do wiki de tag*
- [`WikiPostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts) *(nullable) Id do Post que contém o texto do wiki de tag*

---

### TagSynonyms

- `Id`
- [`SourceTagName`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=tags&pk=tagname)
- [`TargetTagName`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=tags&pk=tagname)
- `CreationDate`
- [`OwnerUserId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users)
- `AutoRenameCount`
- `LastAutoRename`
- `Score`
- [`ApprovedByUserId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users)
- `ApprovalDate`

---

### *Votes*

- `Id`
- [`PostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts)
- `VoteTypeId` *(listados na tabela [`VoteTypes`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types))*
  <sub>1 = AcceptedByOriginator

  2 = UpMod *([voto positivo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157536/200117))*

  3 = DownMod *([voto negativo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157536/200117))*

  4 = Offensive - Ofensivo

  5 = Favorite *(`UserId` também será preenchido)*

  6 = Close - Fechar (a partir de 2013-06-25: votos de fechamento estão **somente** na tabela `PostHistory`)

  7 = Reopen - Reabrir

  8 = BountyStart *(`UserId` e `BountyAmount` também serão preenchidos)*

  9 = BountyClose *(`BountyAmount` também será preenchido)*

  10 = Deletion

  11 = Undeletion

  12 = Spam

  15 = ModeratorReview

  16 = ApproveEditSuggestion</sub>
- [`UserId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users) *(presente apenas se `VoteTypeId in (5,8)`; -1 se o usuário foi deletado)*
- `CreationDate` Apenas a data (`2018-07-31 00:00:00` *[o horário é removido de propósito](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/933/163250) para proteger a privacidade dos usuários)*
- `BountyAmount` (presente apenas se `VoteTypeId in (8,9)`)

---

### xxxTypes

*Não listados aqui:*
- as tabelas `xxxTypes` que listam pares de Id e Nome para `Posts.PostTypeId`, `Votes.VoteTypeId`, etc. Veja [*Show all types*](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types) para uma lista atualizada de todos os tipos.

---

### Todas as tabelas/colunas/tipos

Veja todos os [*T-SQL datatypes*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) e tamanhos/precisões de cada coluna nesta query:

[*List all Fields in all Tables on SEDE*](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/835150/list-all-fields-in-all-tables-on-sede?/)

---

## TIMESTAMPS

Todos os timestamps estão em [**`UTC`**](https://www.epochconverter.com/), formato padrão: `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` (gravados com milissegundos).

**Exemplo de conversão** da hora atual para `PST` (Hora do Pacífico - costa leste dos EUA - incluindo [horário de verão](https://www.google.com/search?q=dst)) usando [`At Time Zone`](https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql):

```
SELECT GetDate() At Time Zone 'UTC' At Time Zone 'Pacific Standard Time'
```

<sub>Para **listar os time zones**: `SELECT * FROM sys.time_zone_info`</sub>

---

O esquema do banco:

[image: SEDE ERD]

O diagrama acima foi construído com base nos dados encontrados na tabela *information_schema.columns*. (Obrigado a [ashleedawg](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1023678/1114977/all-tables-columns-data-typesincl-length-or-precision-in-sede) por reduzir as tabelas ao essencial).

Todas as informações sobre as tabelas e colunas foram compiladas em um script SQL usando Python 3. Os resultados foram validados com as demais informações acima (*and the few idiosyncratic foreign key formations left over were hardcoded in at the end*).

Foi feita então uma engenharia reversa usando *dbschema*.

O script e outros arquivos relacionados estão [no GitHub](https://github.com/leerssej/SEDESchema).

Uma versão interativa do diagrama em HTML pode ser encontrada em https://sedeschema.github.io/

Comment: Em nome da comunidade agradeço pelo imenso trabalho!

Comment: @Isac Obrigado! E eu agradeceria qualquer um que puder traduzir o que faltou :-)